Spring in Kotlin: Getting data from couchbase server using special query brings back an empty object
I have a Spring micro-service that has been working for months now.
The owner wanted to add 2 additional function, one of them required a custom query:
SELECT Meta().id AS __id, *
FROM `bucket`
WHERE _class = "com.....CurrencyDominationDao"
AND lastUpdated >= $1 AND storeId = $2"

The query works well inside couchbase query section online, it retrieve the data as needed.
but when I use it from spring, I get an empty Dao object, only the document ID that is in it.
The same Dao object is used for other queries and is getting the data correctly.
I request the data from the repository using service layer,the data that is coming from the repository is empty, it matches the Dao object default values.
I checked the query logs in couchbase, it is successful. no errors whatsoever.
only when it comes to this query, I get an empty Dao object with the document Id.
I tested the query several times. each time it brings back the right number of data objects it should get from the database, but all of them are empty.
I use reactive structure, using coroutines flow.
how is that possible?
how can I solve it?

Use the built-in variable for the SELECT ... part of your query.
And also for the predicate on _class...
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND iata != $1")
List<Airport> getAllByIataNot(String iata, Pageable pageable);


thank you! that worked! no idea why that one didn't work!

If I had to guess, it's because having fields directly queried means that you'll get the bucket name (or collection name in Server 7+) included at the top level of the results. And this may not be serializing properly. So, I'd recommend (for this reason and for readability in general) to use aliases.
For example, this query:
select *
from `travel-sample`.inventory.hotel
limit 10;

Returns results like this:
[
  {
    "hotel": {
      "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
      "address": "Capstone Road, ME7 3JE",
      // ... etc ...
    }
  },
  {
    "hotel": {
      "name": "The Balmoral Guesthouse",
      "address": "57-59 Balmoral Road, ME7 4NT",
      // ... etc ...
  }
]

While this query:
select h.*
from `travel-sample`.inventory.hotel h
limit 10;

Returns results like this:
[
  {
    "name": "Medway Youth Hostel",
    "address": "Capstone Road, ME7 3JE",
    // ... etc ...
  },
  {
    "name": "The Balmoral Guesthouse",
    "address": "57-59 Balmoral Road, ME7 4NT",
    // ... etc ...
  }
]

So, I'd recommend giving that a try and see if it works.
Also, probably unrelated to your problem, I'd make sure to double check that you really need every field returned by this query (i.e. SELECT *). If you only need a few fields, that's a lot of extra overhead, and fewer fields (combined with covering indexes) can give you much better performance.

Thank you so much for the explanation, the issue is that the requirements I have needs the whole document, also they only have the bucket that has everything, no scopes or anything whatsoever, that is why I only have the bucket name in the query.
